# Model changed listener stops working after inserting data to another named model

Tags: java, jena

I am using Apache Jena's Model Changed Listener but I saw a strange *bug* during my experiments. If we register a model changed listener on a named model from TDB2 dataset everything works as expected. However, problem arises when we insert some data to another named model. The first registered listener stops working after that. Here is the code to reproduce the issue

```
Dataset dataset = TDB2Factory.createDataset();
dataset.getNamedModel("MY_MODEL").register(new MyListener());
Triple t = Triple.create( ... ) // Create any triple, it does not matter what

dataset.begin(TxnType.Write);
dataset.getNamedModel("MY_MODEL").getGraph().add(t); // Callback successfully received
dataset.getNamedModel("TEMP_MODEL").getGraph().add(t);
dataset.getNamedModel("MY_MODEL").getGraph().add(t); // No Callback received. If comment out previous line then callback is received.
dataset.abort();
```

Is this a known bug or this behavior is reported somewhere?

Comment: TDB (1 or 2) does not guarantee the model created by getNamedModel is the same each time. Sometimes this is what you want, sometimes it is not. It does stop a build-up of objects in long-running programs. Use the same java object rather than get a new one each time. (The only internal helper is a one slot cache so that "dataset.getNamedModel(name) ; dataset.getNamedModel(name) ; ... same ..." does not churn java objects too much.)

Comment: @AndyS I understand.. but when registering a listener intention usually is to register it on the underlying graph rather than the particular object. If maintainers agree, I would be happy to submit a PR to change one slot cache to a normal cache..

Comment: For the concern of build up of objects in long running programs, maybe if user is creating named model in a dataset they will want to use it further too, so its a tradeoff..

Comment: For it to work in TDB2 in long running applications, the cache must be finite and drop entries sometime else it could grow without limit. Datasets with large number of very small graphs are not unknown. So the effect will still be there, just more confusing. The cache therefore has to be sensitive to the application pattern. This can be done by the application adding a DatasetGraphWrapper (and wrapping as a Dataset) with its choice of cache policy. This is application code at the point the application obtains the Dataset.

Comment: Okay Got it! Thanks :)